# Install of QGIS 3.2 in OSX - Python 2.7 existing won't let me

Tags: python, macos, qgis

so I am trying to install QGIS on my Mac.  I've used this guide here:

https://www.gislounge.com/installing-qgis-on-the-mac/

My QGIS install came from here:
https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

I get as far along the steps as installing the QGIS 3.pkg but the installation refuses at this point saying it needs Python 3.6 or up.

I have 3.7 installed in fact as per the steps in the guide.  However I also have 2.7 installed - this I understand comes as standard with OSX.

What can I do to get around this?  I don't want to mess with native OSX install and break anything!

I'm on OSX 10.13.6

With thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the QGIS download site:

> *(...)* This package uses the
>   python.org **Python 3.6**, at least version 3.6.5, the "macosx10.9" build - other distributions are not supported. Install packages in the numbered order.

I read this such as meaning that the installation *only* supports 3.6, and no other (lower or higher) releases.

I used the [3.6.6 - 2018-06-27 64-bit installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/python-3.6.6-macosx10.9.pkg) yesterday (from the [Python Releases for Mac OS X](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) link), and everything installed flawlessly.

Comment: Nailed it - thank you.  I don't know why that did not occur to me, thank you again!